# select all rows where array elements exist

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_array
(
  id integer,  
  arr TEXT[]
);
```

I insert sample data:

```
INSERT INTO test_array(id, arr) VALUES (1, '{"a", "b", "c"}');
INSERT INTO test_array(id, arr) VALUES (2, '{"d", "f", "c"}');
INSERT INTO test_array(id, arr) VALUES (3, '{"a", "z", "i"}');
```

I want to get rows where elements {"a", "c"} is exist,
so the result must be:

```
'{"a", "b", "c"}'
'{"d", "f", "c"}'
'{"a", "z", "i"}'
```

I write query:

```
select * from test_array where arr @> '{"a"}' or arr @> '{"c"}';
```

but I want to make query without `or`, in one condition. Is it possible?

When I run `select * from test_array where arr @> '{"a", "c"}';`

it returns me only one row

https://rextester.com/ATMU4521

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@>` means "contains" so all elements from the array on the right hand side must exist in the array on the left hand side. You are looking for the overlaps `&&` operator which [is described as](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) "have elements in common":

```
select * 
from test_array 
where arr && array['a', 'c'];
```

I prefer the `array[]` notation to specify array constant as I don't need to think about nested quotes.